# Xcode - cast CGRect to ID?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a function who get(ID) return(ID) the good information based on languageID.  Work great for string, object(uiButton, etc), but not for INT or CGRect.  But the exemple below are not ok. (goal are ONE fonction who take anything and return anything)

Thanks for suggestions!

```
[bButton setFrame:(CGRect) [Parametres getByLanguage:CGRectMake(262,51,43,31) FrenchID:CGRectMake(272,51,33,31)]];
```

or

```
[bButton setFrame:[Parametres getByLanguage:CGRectMake(262,51,43,31) FrenchID:CGRectMake(272,51,33,31)]];
```

Are not ok with Xcode.

```
+ ( id ) getByLanguage: (id)English FrenchID:(id)French{  
    P66AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.nLanguageId == 0) {
        return French;
    } 
    else {
        return English;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoa provides a wrapper class called `NSValue` that should help you out:

```
 NSValue *rectValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
```

and

```
 CGRect rect = [someNSValue CGRectValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a fundamental limitation of Objective-C — a variable cannot sometimes hold an object and sometimes a primitive value. The best workaround is to return an NSNumber or NSValue object wrapping the real value you want to return, but in order to use the rect or int or whatever, you'll have to extract the actual value from the wrapper object by sending it `[theWrapper rectValue]` or equivalent.